# Fail to define success function a global variable for use in different pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, global-variables

[Fiddle Original Example](http://jsfiddle.net/HANvQ/2/)

[Failed Example](http://jsfiddle.net/HANvQ/5/)

Please take a look at this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "url",
    success: function (data) {

        $(data.query.results.json.json).each(function (index, item) {        
            var title = item.title;
            var ingredient = item.Ingredient; 
            $('.'+title).html(''+ingredient+'')

        });
    },
    error: function () {}
});
```

I have an ajax script in which the success callback function is very page-specific, like on certain pages, I'd rather use this to build the markup:

```
   $(data.query.results.json.json).each(function (index, item) {        
      var title = item.title;
      var ingredient = item.Ingredient; 
      $('.'+ingredient).html(''+ingredient+'<p>+'title'+')
  });
```

Can I make this success callback function a global variable and have its modified versions include on specific pages, something like this:

In the main JS file:

```
var page_markup;
    $.ajax({
        url: "url",
        success: function (data) {
          page_markup();
        },
        error: function () {}
    });
```

In the page file:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Title</title>  
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='mainjsfile.js'></script>
<script>
      page_markup = function(){
         $(data.query.results.json.json).each(function (index, item) {        
          var title = item.title;
          var ingredient = item.Ingredient; 
          $('.'+ingredient).html(''+ingredient+'<p>+'title'+')
         });
       }
</script>
<body>
text......
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20json%20where%20url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fgoo.gl%2F5Lpwxz%22&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback=",
    success: function (data) {
        mysuccess(data);
    },
    error: function () {}
});

var mysuccess =  function (data) {
    $(data.query.results.json.json).each(function (index, item) {        
        var title = item.title;
        var ingredient = item.Ingredient; 
        $('.'+title).html(''+ingredient+'')
    });
};
```

fiddle link:http://jsfiddle.net/9k3nT/